# Brush only parts of an Ellipse in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ellipse, brush

I'm having trouble to find the best way to draw the below shape. I'm using the below code to draw an `Ellipse` on visual layer.

But how can I only brush the quarters? I think it can be done using `LinearGradientBrush` or `RadialGradientBrush` but I don't know how use it.

```
var cntrpoint = space.FlipYAxis(x2, y2);
dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Transparent, pen, cntrpoint, 30, 30);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var geometry = new GeometryGroup();
geometry.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(1, 0, 1, 1)));
geometry.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 1, 1, 1)));
var drawing = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, geometry);
var brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);

dc.DrawEllipse(brush, pen, cntrpoint, 30, 30);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens. Can you please tell me what `RectangleGeometry` is doing here? I'm having a hard time understanding that part.

Comment: The two RectangleGeometries (of width and height `1`) fill the lower left and upper right quadrants of a 2x2 grid. Hence the (relative) coordinates `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)`.

Comment: This answer is really elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to do it in XAML 
(inspired by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670388/3047078):

```
<Image Width="200" Height="200" Margin="20">
  <Image.Source>
    <DrawingImage>
      <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>

          <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen Brush="Black" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                  <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,0"/>
                    <ArcSegment Point="200,100"  SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="100,100"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                  </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
              </PathGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>

          <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen Brush="Black"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="200,100">
                  <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <ArcSegment Point="100,200" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="100,100"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                  </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
              </PathGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>

          <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen Brush="Black"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                  <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,200"/>
                    <ArcSegment Point="0,100" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="100,100"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
                  </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
              </PathGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>

          <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen Brush="Black"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,100">
                  <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <LineSegment Point="0,100"/>
                    <ArcSegment Point="100,0" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="100,100"/>
                  </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
              </PathGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>

        </DrawingGroup>
      </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks Flat, it does the job but what I want is a solution that implements a `Brush`. I don't want to do it combining separate geometries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using  `DrawingBrush` and `GeometryDrawing`

```
<Ellipse Width="300" Height="300" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1.5">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50" />
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to adapt this to my situation. Cause I'm drawing the ellipse in code behind.