# How do I fill a rectangle on canvas with a hatchbrush pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and want to fill a rectangle with a brick pattern. How do I do this? Here is what I have done but can't get it to work since I am missing something. I have researched this without success. Here is my simple code:

```
Rectangle aRect = new Rectangle();
HatchBrush brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.DiagonalBrick,System.Drawing.Color.Black);
aRect.Fill = brush;
```

Comment: The example provided uses XAML. I want to do this in code, not XAML.

Comment: @Clemens: How then would I approach this in WPF?

Comment: Take the XAML from the answer and convert it to C#. You'll find examples on the internet how to create a DawingBrush in code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm researching that now.

Comment: For example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709991/1136211

Comment: You may also keep the DrawingBrush in XAML as a resource. Then use it in code behind with the FindResource method.